# Not able to set the max height of React bootstrap table

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I want to set the maxHeight of my bootstrap table.

I have tried the below logics, but nothing is working for my table.

```
//1st try
componentDidMount() {
 let height = 100;
 this.setState({tableHeight: height + "px"});
}

<BootstrapTable style={{color: this.state.colorCr }}
  data={this.state.crArray}
  headers={this.props.state.options.headers}
  columns={crCol}
  maxHeight={this.state.tableHeight}
>
</BootstrapTable>

//2nd try

<BootstrapTable style={{color: this.state.colorCr }}
   data={this.state.crArray}
   headers={this.props.state.options.headers}
   columns={crCol}
   height={100}
>
</BootstrapTable>

//3rd try

<BootstrapTable style={{color: this.state.colorCr }}
   data={this.state.crArray}
   headers={this.props.state.options.headers}
   columns={crCol}
   bodyStyle={ { maxHeight: '100px' } }
>
</BootstrapTable>
```

Can anyone please tell me what wrong I am doing, or any other way to set the max height of `Bootstrap` table. Any help will be very much appreicated.

Comment: how about wrap BootstrapTable in a <div> with height?

Comment: That's good idea, but problem is if I will keep <Bootstrap> table inside <div>, then maintaining maxHeight will be easy, but I need to give vertical scroll bar also to the table, if I will give it in div style, then thead of Bootstrap table will also scroll, but I just want tbody to scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React Bootstrap Table itself adds a wrapper div to the `<table>` tag. So no need to add extra `<div>`. Please go through the below link first in which they have provided an example to add classes and ids to customize the table.

[Customized id and class table](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/storybook/index.html?selectedKind=Basic%20Table&selectedStory=Customized%20id%20and%20class%20table&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel)

In your case, you have to

1. First add a css rule for a `wrapperClasses` prop in your css file mentioning the `max-height` to desired value and `overflow` to `auto`. That will be applicable for wrapper div and will help you to have a scroll bar.
2. To make header sticky and only body to be scrolled, add one more following css rule for `<th>`. It's up to you to have a class scope limitations. I wanted to have it only for the table under the specific div in my project. Otherwise, just put `table thead th`.

```
.<class-name-of-wrapper-div> table thead th {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Hope it solves your problem.